# Is there any way to run glue job without installing required packages every time by storing the packages in s3 location

Tags: aws-glue

Every time when my glue job is running it is downloading all the packages again and again due to that it is taking more than 15 extra seconds.
Is there any other way to reduce that extra time by providing all the installed packages if there is a way please tell me how to create and give connection to that packages.

I am attaching the issue I am facing below

````
2021-10-19T18:18:03.481+05:30   Creating /glue/lib/installation/site.py
2021-10-19T18:18:03.483+05:30   Processing redshift_utils-0.1-py3.6.egg
2021-10-19T18:18:03.484+05:30   Copying redshift_utils-0.1-py3.6.egg to /glue/lib/installation
2021-10-19T18:18:03.487+05:30   Adding redshift-utils 0.1 to easy-install.pth file
2021-10-19T18:18:03.489+05:30   Installed /glue/lib/installation/redshift_utils-0.1-py3.6.egg
2021-10-19T18:18:03.490+05:30   Processing dependencies for redshift-utils==0.1
2021-10-19T18:18:03.493+05:30   Searching for pymssql==2.1.4
2021-10-19T18:18:03.493+05:30   Reading https://pypi.org/simple/pymssql/
2021-10-19T18:18:03.771+05:30   Downloading https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/84/80/de3af1d2d76792841a94196c6c06c67fb4c3b11ae3a5f5811c5069b94d76/pymssql-2.1.4-cp36-cp36m-manylinux1_x86_64.whl#sha256=d30001a9e00dbbb7ca04922eeb4df89e946bb083bbf7114667b8cbb7e08d9a0c
2021-10-19T18:18:03.868+05:30   Best match: pymssql 2.1.4```
````

Comment: how are you passing this packages to your Glue job?

Comment: I am giving the library path to egg file in advance options when creating the job

Comment: I am also doing the same but it is taking up to 15+ seconds to load them.